# HREF - value gets reset automatically -

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, attributes, href

I have a link `< a id="testLink" href="https://www.test.com?name=test" onclick="return (isValidAction())" />`

i have used `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.15.2/URI.min.js"></script>` library to manipulate the href values like the following,

```
function isValidAction(){   

// Get our <a> element
    var link = document.getElementById("testLink");

    // Use URI.js to work with the URI
    var uri = URI(link.href);

    // Get the query string as an object
    var qs = uri.query(true);
    qs.name= "testValue1";


    // Update the URI object
    uri.query(qs);

    // Set our new HREF on the <a> element
    link.href = uri.toString();

   return confirm("Do you want to Cotinue?");

}
```

I do this onClick event of the `<a....../>` i tried to print the link values

```
console.log(link.href);
```

it prints the right URL but after the console print the values are getting reset and the ordinal values remains same.

could some one help me as what could be the wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX i am using the same code, it does not even show any error on the console and No error too

Comment: @JaromandaX my edit makes clear now

Comment: @JaromandaX it prints the right url after modifying the value that is what i mentioned also but when i see the url in the browser the value is not reset

Comment: @JaromandaX i get to see the URL browser itselt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86665/discussion-between-tony-and-jaromanda-x).